# How to wrap an Interface within another JSON?

Tags: typescript, angular

Currently I have an interface defined as

```
export interface IBlog {
    id?: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    type: number;
}
```

And that'll render some json that looks like this

```
{
 "title":"What the hell",
 "body":"A body a body",
 "type":1
}
```

However, my backend is expecting something like

```
  {
   "blog":{
    "title":"What the hell",
    "body":"A body a body",
    "type":1        
   }
  }
```

I'm using `JSON.stringify()` to render my json and I'm wondering if it's possible to get the outer json wrapping. I would like to do this WITHOUT wrapping it in an outer interface if possible

Comment: can't you just wrap it like `JSON.stringify({blog: yourIBlogObject})` ?

Comment: That did the trick :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're asking how to represent this in typescript or how to create a js object that will have this structure.

If it's the first then:

```
interface IBlog {
    id?: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    type: number;
}

interface IRequest {
    blog: IBlog;
}
```

If the second then:

```
let blog: IBlog = ...
let request: IRequest = { blog: blog };
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified but I was wondering how to do it without creating another interface. Would it be possible to somehow get it so I only have IBlog?